# # Homomorphisms between $(\{\pm1,\pm i\},\times)$ and quotient group of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

> How many non-trivial homomorphisims are there between $(\{\pm1,\pm i\},\times)$ and quotient group of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$?

I have drawn their Cayley tables and have found that each of the entries have a $1-1$ correspondence across the tables. How do I find the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $i^2=-1, i^3=-i, i^4 = 1$ the group $\{\pm 1, \pm i\}$ is a cyclic group of order $4$ generated by $i$, just like $\mathbb Z\big/4\mathbb Z$ is a cyclic group of order $4$ generated by $\overline 1$. Thus, the two groups are isomorphic. Now the question is equivalent to asking how many non-trivial endomorphisms $\mathbb Z\big/4\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z\big/4\mathbb Z$ exist.

Any homomorphism on a cyclic group is determined by the image of the generator. How many possible images are there, do all of them give homomorphisms?

Comment: I have #Automorphisms = $\phi(4) = 2$. (Out of which I guess 1 is trivial). Do I have other endomorphisms?

Comment: You are not asking for automorphisms though. Try to answer the questions I asked. Also, an automorphism on a non-trivial group is never a trivial homomorphism. A trivial homomorphisms is one that maps everything to the identity!

Comment: No I am not asking for automorphisms, but they also are endomorphisms. Are there any extra, I mean can I map a $2\times 2$ grid in the multiplication table to a $1 \times 1$ grid. I don't feel so(So my ans. = 2). Just asking for clarification.

Comment: Found some other mappings. Thanks for the help!!